# Change the body background based on specific div's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have a `div` which will load youtube videos with ajax and the div ID would be change based on the video is playing on it.

I was wondering if there is anyway to get the div ID and change the body background based on that.

```
<div id="video-load">
        <iframe id="player_ID" video-id="player_ID"  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= get_field('youtube_video_id_main'); ?>?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=2&showinfo=0&vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

$('iframe').each(function(){
    $(body).css('background', $(.this).attr('video-id'));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whatever `.you` is should be wrapped in quotes. `$('.you').attr('video-id')`

Comment: I think you meant: `$(this).attr('video-id')`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly and cabbott sorry i was playing around with the code and accidentally post the wrong code here. Anyway do you guys have any idea? or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `(body)` by `('body')`. The **FIDDLE**:

http://jsfiddle.net/hz5rppy7/

Comment: The iframe is not in the `DOM` yet when you run the code

Comment: Check now: http://jsfiddle.net/vPELX/81/ I just move the `each` block of code inside the function, right after you add the iframe to the `DOM`.